# How can I write an O(1) algorithm to return an element NOT smallest in array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, runtime

Given an array of unique elements = [ 2, 6, 11, 21, 5 ].  How can I write an O(1) algorithm that returns an element that is not the smallest in the array?

```
//  I tried... but not sure if this is O(1)   -  runtime

$arr = [2, 6, 11, 21, 5];
$smallest = $arr[0];

function returnSmallest() {

   for( i = 1; i < $arr.length; i++ )  
   {
      if($arr[i] < $smallest)
   {
     $smallest = $arr[i];
   }
}  return $smallest;

}();

print($smallest);
```

Comment: Not clear for me what what you want. Do you want the smallest, as in the code, or an element which is *not* the smallest, as in the title?

Comment: If you want an element which is not the smallest, just compare the two first elements. O(1) !

Comment: The question in title contradicts with the question in body. Do you want the smallest element or not the smallest?

Comment: Yes,  should return an element that is NOT smallest in the array (correction to the title). I am not sure if my attempt at writing the code /algorithm is correct and represents a runtime of O(1)

Comment: A simple answer could be: `$smallest = ($arr[0] > $arr[1]) ? $arr[0] : $arr[1];`

Comment: @MrCEO, your code is O(n) since you are looping over the entire array, Damien's answer is correct you can just compare first 2 items in array and return the largest ( which btw is O(1) )

Comment: Your code returns the smallest element. It is O(n) as it examines the *n* elements. Impossible to do better if you want the smallest, as you *need* to examine all elements in this case. You don't need to examine all elements if you simply want an element which is not the smallest

Comment: But how do I check through all the element to determine which is the smallest,  so I could return any of the others? (which would be greater than the smallest?

Comment: Why do you want to check all elements ?

Comment: @MrCEO: you stated that the array is of unique elements, so you just need to take the biggest one of any two elements. You do not need to scan the entire array in order to find the smallest one.

Comment: @pavan skipo But what about the other elements in the array. Could you clarify why the first 2 elements?

Comment: @MrCEO It's simple when u compare 2 elements and you return the largest, then obviously other element is smaller right? which satisfies your condition "return NOT smallest item in array".
let me give as example [10, 4, 3, 11] --> (10 > 4) ---> return(10) which is not the smallest in array.

Comment: @pavan skipo  Yes, that makes perfect sense. I feel I'm still missing something.   Is there any scenario (e.g.  re-arrangement of elements in the array) that would make comparing the first two elements to return otherwise (wrong result?)

Comment: @Damien I appreciate your feedback - was very helpful!  There's no need to scan the entire array.

Comment: @MrCEO Happy to have helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is vague. If you want to return the smallest element, there is no O(1) algorithm to do that if you are not storing the elements in a sorted array.

If you want to return an element that is not smallest, your code is wrong, since it is returning the smallest element. You can just return the largest between the first two elements and that is O(1).